# Multiple authentication attributes

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I`m working on my website using .net web-api as back .
Now I made different authentication attributes on the web site such as users employees and admin .
for my question how can I use multiple authentication attributes on a controller?

```
  public class AuthFilterManager : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {
        public bool AllowMultiple => throw new NotImplementedException();


        public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var auth = context.Request.Headers.Authorization;

            string[] UserNameAndPass = (auth.Parameter).Split(':');
            string UserName = UserNameAndPass[0];
            string Pass = UserNameAndPass[1];

            Luxury_wheelsEntities entities = new Luxury_wheelsEntities();

            Management manager = entities.Managements.FirstOrDefault(m => m.User_name == UserName);

            if (auth != null && auth.Scheme == "LuxuryWheelsLogin")
            {

                if (LoginSecurity.CheckManagerLogin(UserName, Pass))
                {

                    var Claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,(manager.ID)),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,(manager.Full_name)),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Gender,(manager.Sex))
                    };

                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Claims, "Token");
                    context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { identity });
                }
                else
                {
                    context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

seperatly the AuthFilterEmployee and the AuthFilterManager works just fine.

```
   [AuthFilterEmployee ]

        [AuthFilterManager] 
        [Authorize]

        public IEnumerable<User> Get()
        {
            return LuxuryWheelsDB.Users;
        }
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing this because every attribute will be executed. Instead, make a single attribute that takes parameters. Like `[AuthFilter(UserType.Employee, UserType.Manager)]` (as a poor example, but demonstrates my point)

Comment: @DavidG thank you will try, can you give me an example maybe?